# What is an efficient way to reduce and merge a list(list(dict())) where some of the dictionaries might have the same keys but different values

Tags: python, structure

Context:
I have a list of Organization IDs where each organization ID has multiple account ID and email pairs. Each email is associated with one account ID per organization (organization ID) (unique). Not all emails are in each of the organizations but some emails are in multiple organizations or even all of them. For example, if there are 5 organizations, each organization has an unknown number of account IDs, email pairs. The account IDs are unique regardless of the organization they are associated with, but there are some emails across multiple organizations associated with a different account IDs.

My data is in the following structure and I am trying to do this in python:

```
# Note: Each AccountID Value is unique across the board
# Note: Emails are unique per organization, but can be in multiple organizations.
[
    [
        # The value for OrganizationID is the same throughout the list of dictionaries.
        {
            "some-email A": "AccountID",
            "OrganizationID": "Organization A"  # <- The ID is just a string of numbers.
        },
        {
            "some-email B": "AccountID",
            "OrganizationID": "Organization A"
        },
        {
            "some-email C": "AccountID",
            "OrganizationID": "Organization A"
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
    [
        {
            "some-email C": "AccountID",   #. <- Also in organization A but different Account ID
            "OrganizationID": "Organization LK"
        },
        {
            "some-email K": "AccountID",
            "OrganizationID": "Organization LK"
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

Order does not matter!
My final goal is to turn this into the following new data structure.

```
# Note: Reference is just a list of strings where each string is 
# a concatenation of the "OrganizationID:AccountID" of the respective email.
[
    {
        "Email": "some-email A",
        "Reference": [
            "[Organization A]:[Account ID of "some-email A" in Organization A if exists]",
            ...
            "[Organization X]:[Account ID of "some-email A" in Organization X if exists]",
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
    {
        "Email": "some-email C",
        "Reference": [
            "[Organization A]:[Account ID of "some-email C" in Organization A if exists]",
            ...
            "[Organization LK]:[Account ID of "some-email C" in Organization LK if exists]",
            ...
        ]
    },
]
```

My current set of data has over 1000 organizations and each organization has an arbitrary number of accounts. Some organizations may only have one or two accounts but others have over 600 accounts. No organization has Zero accounts.

Edit:
My current solution is as follows: But I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way of approaching this.

```
re = list()
seen = set()
for _p in dt: # <- this is the first data set list(list(dict()))
    for x in _p: # <- Each dictionary in the list(dict())
        em = list(x.keys())[1] # <- some-email key
        if em not in seen:
            seen.add(em)
            re.append({
                "Email": em,
                "Reference": [x["OrganizationID"] + ":" + x[em]]
            })
        else:
            d = next(i for i in re if i['Email'] == em)
            d["Reference"].append(x["OrganizationID"] + ":" + x[em])
```

Comment: is `"OrganizationID", "Organization A"` supposed to be `"OrganizationID": "Organization A"`. Otherwise your data has a syntax error

Comment: Whoops! I did a quick edit and fixed that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing will require nested for loops because of the way the data is structured, but I think you'll get better performance if you remove the `if em not in seen` clause because that requires its own iteration over a set which isn't necessary and not creating the set in the first place will reduce overhead.  Here is my approach:

```py
dct = {}
for i1 in range(len(emails)):
    for i2 in range(len(emails[i1])):
        email = next(iter(emails[i1][i2].items()))
        org = emails[i1][0]["OrganizationID"]
        if dct.get(email[0]):
            dct[email[0]].append({org: email[1]})
        else:
            dct[email[0]] = [{org: email[1]}]
```

It looks into each key, value pair of each organization and then appends the org+id combo if it doesn't already exist under the email. This is better because dct.get() does not iterate over a list of keys, it checks the hash table for the key and if it doesn't exist then it returns `None`